# asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $1: 217027642536 (value out of int32 range)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working on a project that uses FastAPI alongside Pydantic and SQLAlchemy. I'm also using encode/databases to manage database connections. But for some weird reason, I get `asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $1: 217027642536 (value out of int32 range)` anytime I try saving to the database. Here's what my code looks like:

`database.py`

```
...
...
currencies = Table(
    'currencies',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(50)),
    Column('price', Float),
    Column('price_date', DateTime),
    Column('price_timestamp', DateTime),
    Column('market_cap', Integer)
)

database = Database(DATABASE_URL)
```

`database_manager.py`

```
...
...
async def add_currency(payload: Currency):
    query = currencies.insert().values(**payload.dict())
    return await database.execute(query=query)
```

`endpoints.py`

```
...
...
@endpoints.post('/', response_model=CurrencyOutput, status_code=201)
async def add_currency():
    data = check_currency_price()

    payload = Currency(
        name=data['name'],
        price=data['price'],
        price_date=data['price_date'],
        price_timestamp=data['price_timestamp'],
        market_cap=data['market_cap']
    )

    currency_id = await database_manager.add_currency(payload)
    response = {
        'id': currency_id,
        **payload.dict()
    }

    return response
```

`models.py`

```
...
...
class Currency(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
    price_date: datetime
    price_timestamp: datetime
    market_cap: int


class CurrencyOutput(Currency):
    id: int
```

`services.py`

```
def check_currency_price():
    response = httpx.get(
        'https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?' +
        'key=somerandomAPIkey&ids=BTC&interval=1d,30d&convert=USD'
    )

    return response.json()[0]
```

I can't see anything wrong with this. Someone, please tell me what the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically having Integer Overflow, **Int32** represents `2^31 - 1`, that means it can store the values in range **-2147483648 to 2147483648**  but the value you are trying to insert is bigger than `2^31`

```
2**31 > 217027642536
Out: False
```

So you need to use SQLAlchemy's **BigInteger** type represents **Int64** it also represents `2^63 - 1` which can store the values in range negative and positive **9,223,372,036,854,775,807**

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger

currencies = Table(
    'currencies',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(50)),
    Column('price', Float),
    Column('price_date', DateTime),
    Column('price_timestamp', DateTime),
    Column('market_cap', BigInteger)
)                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Changing market's Column Type with the **BigInteger** should solve the problem, but be careful bigger types uses more memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! But I still got the error after using BigInteger

Comment: Yes, I am. It's the same thing

Comment: If you have pgadmin you can confirm that your table still uses Integer type for that column, because it's created that way you should change the columns data type again or if you dont have data in that table you can recreate it.

Comment: Uhmmm, that's true. Let me try recreating

Comment: For changing columntype you can use `ALTER TABLE currencies ALTER COLUMN market_cap TYPE bigint`

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I got through that. Now, there's another version of the error:
`asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $4: datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 13, 0, 0, tzi... (can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes)`

Comment: `price_timestamp=data['price_timestamp'].replace(tzinfo=None)` btw, that's completely different case normally you should ask a new question according to stackoverflow guidelines,  but the solution is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate!

Comment: OK! This is crazy. I got `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`

Comment: I think installing `pytz` should fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219776/discussion-between-caspian-and-yagizcan-degirmenci).